# Confusion in Granularity for Time Series Data

Tags: mongodb, time-series, granularity

I am confused about Granularity for Time Series Data official document example:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/core/timeseries/timeseries-granularity/

**For example, if you are recording weather data from thousands of sensors but only record data from each sensor once per 5 minutes, set granularity to "minutes" . Setting the granularity to hours groups up to a month’s worth of data ingest events into a single bucket, resulting in longer traversal times and slower queries. Setting it to seconds leads to multiple buckets per polling interval, many of which might contain only a single document.**

But just above the example, it says setting `seconds`, will group `granularity bucket limit` up to 1 hour. So, shouldn’t setting `seconds` be appropriate here?

Also, I found the statement contradictory in the second example of `bucketMaxSpanSeconds`.

**For the weather station example with 5 minute sensor intervals, you could fine tune bucketing by setting the custom bucketing parameters to 300 seconds, instead of using a granularity of "minutes".**

So, in the 1st example, we are avoiding `seconds` (whose granularity bucket limits 1 hour) and choosing minutes (whose `granularity bucket limit` is 24 hours). But in the second example, we are setting it to as little as 5 minutes.